# How to check only one argument in a unit test in c#, when a multiargument method is called?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am writing a unit test for a method. In this method a method of the EventsApi with a similar signature is called:

```
Task<EventCollection?> GetEvents(DateTime? createdFrom = null, DateTime? createdTo = null, string? source = null, string? type = null);
```

And I would like to make sure, that the method is called with a specified source. How to do it, what to put here?

```
eventsApi.Verify(x => x.GetEvents(<what_to_put_here?>));
```

Comment: `eventsApi.Verify(x => x.GetEvents( source: "123abc" ));`

Comment: In case you are using Moq, you may pass the other arguments as It.IsAny<>. `eventsApi.Verify(x => x.GetEvents(It.IsAny<DataTime>(), It.IsAny<DataTime>(), "The Specic Source", It.IsAny<String>()));`